# Problem saving on sdcard of Nexus S

Tags: android, save, sd-card, ioexception, nexus-s

I cannot save a text file on a Nexus S. State is mounted, path is ok (`/sdcard/filename`), there is a permission in my manifest file for extenal storage.

The program gives an `IOException` on this line:

```
File file = new File(path, fileName + ".txt");
```

I have no idea how to detect the problem, especially if it works fine on a Galaxy Mini. I have been struggling saving a txt file on Samsung Galaxy for some time, but made it work by removing a line from the manifest file defining the min sdk version. It did not accept any min sdk version in fact, so I removed it altogether for now...

Can anyone help?

Comment: I think it will help if you post the code where you create "path" and "filename". Also if you paste the exception, if any.

Answer (score 1):

```
String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/";
File file = new File(path+fileName + ".txt");
```

try it out

Comment: It seems the problem comes from the API version: getExternalStorageDirectory() works for < API7, so it worked on Galaxy mini, however it could not work on Nexus S which needs

Comment: (sorry, not used to this system, comments expiring and what not) Nexus S which needs getExternalFilesDir(). I changed the target Android version to 2.2 and things work, but still it is not clear to me how to make it work on 2.1 too.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal), you should first check that external media is mounted:

```
if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()))
```

and then use it via [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29).

If you plan to save publicly accessed files (pictures, videos, music, etc..) then use [`Environment. getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29) with appropriate argument.